# Showing labels in frames next to each other with TKinter

Tags: python, twitter, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tweepy

I'm using TKinter to render popular tweets(from twitter API using tweepy). The problem is that the frames of the tweets are positioned at the bottom of each other. I've tried to change the side of the frame but nothing has changed.

The problem is shown below

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OUmt.png)

I want the tweets to be like this next to each other:

[The desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNTuw.png)

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tweepy
from local import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from ttk import Frame, Style
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
sa_ID = 23424938
large_text_size = 12
text_size = 20

#create obj in the root page (main windows)
root= Tk()
#make bg black
root.configure(background='black')
screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (screenWidth, screenHeight))
root.configure(background='#000000')  # black

canvas = Canvas(
    background='#000000',  # black
    borderwidth=-5,
    height=500,
    relief='flat',
    width=500)

canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
#create invisible container
topframe= tk.Frame(root,background='black')
topframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand = YES)
label24 = Label(topframe, text="Popular Tweets", bg='black', fg='white',font=('minionpro', text_size)).pack(anchor=CENTER)

bottomframe= Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side= BOTTOM)

#, padx=20, pady=20
# name the window
root.title("The news Portal")
trends1 = api.trends_place(id=sa_ID)
data = trends1[0]
# grab the trends
trends = []
trends=data['trends']
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, background='black')
listbox.pack(side=RIGHT)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)


for trend in trends:
    if trend['name'].startswith('#'):
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=trend['name'], result_type='popular').items(1):
            leftframe = tk.Frame(canvas, background='black', borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
            leftframe.pack()
            label6 = Label(leftframe, text=('Tweet by: @' + status.user.screen_name, status.text), bg='black',fg='white',
                               font=('minionpro', large_text_size)).pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=N)
            #label23 = Label(leftframe, text="\n", bg='black', fg='white').pack(side=BOTTOM)


            #print status.text
#windows is continously there untill uder close it (never close)
root.mainloop()
```

The thing is that i'm missing out a lot of tweets because of this layout. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Searching SO for `[tkinter] grid Labels` returns 435 results.  I imagine that some of the first 10 or 20 should help.

Comment: I did actually search and i did applied multiple solutions like using place, grid and even making a for loop. I don't see that you've added new information by writing this comment :) @TerryJanReedy

Comment: You did not say the new info in this comment in the question, so I could not know.  Many beginners obviously do not know about searching SO, as a simple search turns up duplicates.  In any case, your desired output is a grid of fixed size read-only text widgets.  Possible because of tweet limit.  Either Label or Text might work.  Latter is more complicated, but allows different fonts and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the pack() layout - you give up your ability to decide the spacing between elements in frames. Tk just makes the elements take up the minimum amount of space within their assigned frame. If you instead use the grid() layout, you can arrange things more specifically within frames, and decide how much of the frame you want them to take up. For examples and usage, see the effbot description of grid: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: _"When you use the pack() layout - you give up your ability to decide the spacing between elements in frames."_ - that's not quite true. You can use the options `padx`, `pady`, `ipadx` and `ipady` to add additional padding.

Comment: Fair enough - it just becomes a bit harder to say for sure where things will be placed especially between frames.

Comment: @BryanOakley ive tried to use grid but the same problem happened. Please, can you suggest a way to reach to the desired picture attached above? :(

Comment: @Mochla can you show me how to use grid in my case? I've tried it and the same problem happened. All i want is to fill the frame with these label of tweets side to side.if the row is full then the label will go to the next row to fill the whole frame :(